# Trigger allowing duplicates when inserting data using dataloader, plese help me to rectify the code

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

Am inserting 300 records of account data using dataloader, which have some duplicates. The below code doesn't worked in catching the duplicates. Please add your suggestion to fix this.

Trigger :

```
trigger PreventDuplicate on Account (before insert, before update){
    Map<string,account> oldMapAcc = new Map<string,account>();
    for(Account a :trigger.new){
        if((a.name!= null) && (trigger.isInsert )|| (trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).name != a.name )){
            if(oldMapAcc.containskey(a.name)){
                a.name.addError('Another new account have same name');
            }else{
                oldMapAcc.put(a.name,a);
            }
        }
    }
    for(Account a: [select id, name from account where name in : oldMapAcc.keyset()]){
        account acc = oldMapAcc.get(a.name);
        acc.name.addError('An account with this name already exists');
    } 
}
```

Comment: Idea is that you need to check not only records which are in DB now, but records that are inserted in current transaction chunk as well

Comment: Suggest you swap to using the platform's [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0) mechanism rather than use your own code.

Comment: if((a.name!= null) && (trigger.isInsert )|| (trigger.oldmap.get(a.id).name != a.name )){
if(oldMapAcc.containskey(a.name)){
a.name.addError('Another new account have same name');
}else{
oldMapAcc.put(a.name,a);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below:

```
trigger PreventDuplicate on Account (before insert, before update){
    Map<string,account> oldMapAcc = new Map<string,account>();
    Map<id,account> dupAccMap = new Map<id,account>();
    for(Account a :trigger.new){
        if(!oldMapAcc.contains(a.name)) {
            oldMapAcc.add(a.name, a);
        } else {
            Account anotherAcc = oldMapAcc.get(a.name);
            anotherAcc.addError('Another new account have same name');
            dupAccMap.Add(anotherAcc.id, anotherAcc);
            a.addError('An account with this name already exists');
            dupAccMap.Add(a.id, a);
        }
    }
    update dupAccMap.values();
}
```